# Why is MariaDB using localhost when using TCP?

Tags: mysql, authentication, mariadb

I installed MariaDB via Nix and I am having trouble connecting via TCP.

I have users such as:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
+---------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| User          | Host      | Password                                  |
+---------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
|               | localhost |                                           |
| foo           | %         | *E8D46CE25265E545D225A8A6F1BAF642FEBEE5CB |
+---------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.004 sec)
```

(there are other rows but that's all for `foo`)

If I try and connect with user `foo`:

```
[1] jason@goodness> mysql -h127.0.0.1 -ufoo -pbar
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'foo'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

And without the password (where I think it falls back to the anonymous user somehow):

```
jason@goodness> mysql -h127.0.0.1 -ufoo
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 20
Server version: 10.6.7-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT USER(), CURRENT_USER();
+---------------+----------------+
| USER()        | CURRENT_USER() |
+---------------+----------------+
| foo@localhost | @localhost     |
+---------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

**Q1** Why does the error message and `USER()` function both say `foo@localhost` instead of `foo@127.0.0.1`?

I tried the same thing with MySQL 5.7 and it says `foo@127.0.0.1` like I would expect.

The status contradicts this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> status
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.7-MariaDB, for osx10.17 (arm64) using  EditLine wrapper

Connection id:      6
Current database:
Current user:       foo@localhost
SSL:            Not in use
Current pager:      less -R
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server:         MariaDB
Server version:     10.6.7-MariaDB MariaDB Server
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    utf8mb3
Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb3
TCP port:       3306
Uptime:         1 min 51 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 49  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 37  Open tables: 30  Queries per second avg: 0.441
--------------
```

Here it says the "current user" is `foo@localhost` which is not true according to `CURRENT_USER()` (nor any other errors which say the current user).

It also says that the connection is `127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP` so I don't know why `USER()`, `CURRENT_USER()`, and `status` would all say `@localhost`.

**Q2** Is this inconsistency related to the access denied error (because there is no `foo@localhost`) or is that a red herring?

**Q3** How do I login with `foo` via TCP?

Comment: why do you think it doesn't use TCP? and why do you care if it uses a loopback IP instead of the alias `localhost`? I'd start by carefully reading this document: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connecting-to-mariadb/

Comment: Because the error says `'foo'@'localhost'`. I have read the docs and `localhost` is not the loopback IP, it is an unfortunate name that is used to mean that it is connecting via a Unix socket file.

Comment: Where did you read that? `localhost` is a hostname which gets resolved  to the IP `127.0.0.1` or if you use IPv6 `::1`. There is no difference between a connection to `localhost` and a connection to `127.0.0.1` other than one uses the hostname and the other directly uses the IP address.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql-command-line-client/#linuxunix.
"Note that localhost is a special value. Using 127.0.0.1 is not the same thing. The latter will connect to the mysqld server through TCP/IP."

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I must not have finished reading [Troubleshooting Connection Issues](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/troubleshooting-connection-issues/#localhost-and).

The solution is either to add a new user specific to localhost, or to remove the anonymous localhost user.

To remove the anonymous localhost user:

```sql
drop user ''@'localhost';
```

It is a bit strange how `localhost` in this context doesn't seem to have the same special meaning like it does for the [mysql client](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql-command-line-client/#linuxunix).